# Benders Decomposition Problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, benders-decomposition

$$r_{m_h,s}(n)=\frac B{m_hb_\ell s}\log_2(1+\gamma_{m_h,s}(n))$$

How to deal with multiple subproblems in **Benders decomposition** when the original objective function is in **product form** of an integer and multiple continuous variables within a **log** function term?

\begin{align}\max_{a,p,d_n}&\quad R_t-\eta_{EE}P_t^+\\\text{s.t.}&\quad (13)-(36)\end{align}

Comment: Can you provide more details about the original problem?

Comment: The original problem is given in fig, where _R_ consists of a log function, and each variable is also linked with this function.

Comment: The graphics are too small to read, can you enter them as proper MathJax instead, or as well?

Comment: I am looking abstract level of decomposition details for such kind of problem. Could anyone refer me to the multiple subproblems example of Bender Decomposition?